# How to create a user in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a new User in a Django project by the following code, but the highlighted line fires an exception.

```
def createUser(request):
    userName = request.REQUEST.get('username', None)
    userPass = request.REQUEST.get('password', None)
    userMail = request.REQUEST.get('email', None)

    # TODO: check if already existed

    **user = User.objects.create_user(userName, userMail, userPass)**
    user.save()

    return render_to_response('home.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Any help?

Comment: WHat kind of exception?

Comment: @user1364223 Exception traceback?

Comment: I think User.objects.create should work. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#create

Answer (score 261, accepted):

The correct way to create a user in Django is to use the create_user function. This will handle the hashing of the password, etc..

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = User.objects.create_user(username='john',
                                 email='jlennon@beatles.com',
                                 password='glass onion')
```

Comment: will this hash the password ?

Comment: @mp3por - Yes. 

For full documentation, go here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user

Comment: how/where do I run this? If I just run that code I get `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.` EDIT: this works `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings.dev python manage.py shell < register-user.py`

Comment: As an update for more modern Django, use `from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model` and `user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(...`

Comment: @keithhackbarth in which file should I insert this code in the django file structure?

Comment: Above documentation link is broken.  Here's the source code for `create_user`: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L143 (you can see that it hashes the password)

Comment: Django doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#topics-auth-creating-users

Comment: Make sure to do ```user.save()``` in the end.

Comment: @Emily you don't need to call .save(), because .create_user() both instantiate the object AND saves it to db.

Additionnaly, you can verify for yourself that the passwords are hashed. If you go to the admin pagem, click Users & clik the user your created, you'll the details of hte hash, salt & algo used to hash the passwor.d

Answer (score 24):

Have you confirmed that you are passing actual values and not `None`?

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def createUser(request):
    userName = request.REQUEST.get('username', None)
    userPass = request.REQUEST.get('password', None)
    userMail = request.REQUEST.get('email', None)

    # TODO: check if already existed
    if userName and userPass and userMail:
       u,created = User.objects.get_or_create(userName, userMail)
       if created:
          # user was created
          # set the password here
       else:
          # user was retrieved
    else:
       # request was empty

    return render(request,'home.html')
```

Comment: If they are None wont the .is_valid() method fail ?

Answer (score 15):

**Bulk user creation with `set_password`**

I you are creating several test users, `bulk_create` is much faster, but we can't use `create_user` with it.

`set_password` is another way to generate the hashed passwords:

```
def users_iterator():
    for i in range(nusers):
        is_superuser = (i == 0)
        user = User(
            first_name='First' + str(i),
            is_staff=is_superuser,
            is_superuser=is_superuser,
            last_name='Last' + str(i),
            username='user' + str(i),
        )
        user.set_password('asdfqwer')
        yield user

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, **options):
        User.objects.bulk_create(iter(users_iterator()))
```

Question specific about password hashing: [How to use Bcrypt to encrypt passwords in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907663/how-to-use-bcrypt-to-encrypt-passwords-in-django)

Tested in Django 1.9.

Comment: much better than accepted; if you are considering programmatically add user you probably automate something for more uses.

Answer (score 6):

If you creat user normally, you will not be able to login as password creation method may b different
You can use default signup form for that

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
```

You can extend that also

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    mobile = forms.CharField(max_length=15, min_length=10)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'mobile' ]
```

Then in view use this class

```
class UserCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'registration/signup.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
```

Comment: I think there's a mistake when creating UserForm by extending forms.ModelForm. I think it should extend UserCreationForm instead

Comment: Also, shouldn't the form_class of UserCreate class view be UserForm?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply use `object.save()` to create user, the raw password will be directly visiable inside the database.
First, not secure.
Second, the encryption of the password is not done, causing the decryptor will use the raw password inside your database to decrypto a wrong password, which makes logging in impossible.
I guess every time you use authenticate function from `django.contrib.auth`, you are actually using the decryptor of it.
And yes, I guess everytime you signing in, your password need to get decrypted again.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a super user from the command line. Make sure you have run migraitons

python manage.py createsuperuser --username=joe --email=joe@example.com

Link to docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/