# Django - Create user crashes

Tags: python, django, addition

I want to add user in a Django app. here's my code, it fires an exception in this line

```
user = User.objects.create(userName, userMail, userPass)
```

Here's the whole code:

```
def createUser(request):
    userName = request.REQUEST.get('username', None)
    userPass = request.REQUEST.get('password', None)
    userMail = request.REQUEST.get('email', None)

    # TODO: check if already existed

    user = User.objects.create(userName, userMail, userPass)
    user.save()

   return render_to_response('home.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Any help?

Comment: What kind of exception? What is input data?

Comment: What is the traceback? What are the values you've given it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django - Create User](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372877/django-create-user)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`create_user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#creating-users) helper function instead of the `create` method. It takes care of hashing the password for you, amongst other things.

```
user = User.objects.create_user(userName, userMail, userPass)
```

As an aside, fetching the values out of the request data dictionary isn't best practice. It's a good idea to learn about django forms and model forms, which will validate input data for you. Once you understand that, there's a [`UserCreationForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm) included with the django auth app which you could use.