# Django - Authenticate with custom User model returns None

Tags: django

I'm following a tutorial (https://thinkster.io/tutorials/django-json-api/authentication) on setting up authentication. I've got to the point where I'm registering users and receiving the tokens back. I can drop into the shell and do;

```
 >>> user = Users.objects.first()
 >>> user.email 
 >>> test@outlook.com
 >>> user.password
 >>> 12345678
```

This shows that the user exists in the database. But when calling my login endpoint;

```
/users/login/
```

the authenticate method returns None.

```
user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
```

I'm printing the email and password just before and it shows the correct data passed in.

I've also set my USERNAME_FIELD to email in my model.

```
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

I've updated my model in my settings to be

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'aemauthentication.User'
```

I've had a look around and the above line in the settings file seems to be the approved answer for most people with this issue.

GitHub link to project - https://github.com/Daniel-sims/aem_1

Answer (score 1):

As per; [Django User Creation successful, but authenticate() returning None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36297046/django-user-creation-successful-but-authenticate-returning-none)

I'd changed the create_user method to take the password as a parameter;

```
user = self.model(username=username, email=self.normalize_email(email), password=password)
```

but you have to call set password, so everythings working fine with;

```
user = self.model(username=username, email=self.normalize_email(email))
user.set_password(password)
```